# Is it possible to access server Internet service for web surfing through ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net

I have a website running on IIS. All clients can connect to my website through internal network. Is it possible to share server Internet service through ASP.NET application?

Comment: TLDR - Yes. ... You just need to make sure the server is visible from the Internet. This may require moving the app on to an Internet facing server or updating some firewall rules. It's possibly a lot more complicated than that depending upon the infrastructure in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two scenarios to consider:

1. You would like to embed a website from the Internet through your application (for instance with iframe) - this is not possible, because the user is still 'downloading' the page to own computer and making connections from there.
2. You would like to get the content (like texts after crawling) from the Internet via your backend service and expose it to your own Webpage - this is possible as long as your ASP.NET backend application has an Internet connection because the website will connect your backend app directly for fetching data.

Comment: My server has Internet access. I want to add a section in my asp.net mvc application in which the user enters their web address and this address is send to the server and the content is sent back to the client and they can see the content in their browser (all the texts and images and ...). Is this scenario possible? How should I start?

Comment: You can start playing with website crawling, like here: https://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-create-a-web-crawler-in-asp-net-c/2511 
But not all pages will render properly AND if the user clicks on any button on the page still it will try to connect to the Internet for getting the sub-page. I would not recommend such an approach without a 4-8 weeks time for proper implementation (and acceptance of limitations that not everything will render properly or you are not able to intercept all redirection calls)